# Unable to download pdf file using wget

Tags: downloads, wget

The website contains a button which I have to click to get the pdf to open.

What I want to do is to use "wget" and the link of that website to download the pdf without me clicking on the button, and then copying the link manually

I used the layer option -l1 but that didn't work.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Can you give a link to the problem site and button?

Comment: Yes, the link is [ https://www.zeewolde.nl/gemeente/formulieren-pdf_42836/ ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Reading your question again I think I didn't understand it correctly. If you want `wget` to recursively download all PDFs linked on https://www.zeewolde.nl/gemeente/formulieren-pdf_42836/, you need to tell it with the `-r` (or `--recursive`) flag in addition to the max depth. Additionally, if you want `wget` to figure out the actual filenames, you can use the experimental `--content-disposition` option. So the command would be:

```
wget --recursive --level=1 --content-disposition "https://www.zeewolde.nl/gemeente/formulieren-pdf_42836/"
```

Note that while you *can* specify file extensions to be downloaded using the `--accept` option, you'd have to additionally accept `php` to make `wget` download the files in the first place. That will, however, download *every* `php` file. It's probably easier to just download everything and manually delete the files you're not interested in.

---

*Original Answer:*

You probably didn't enclose the URL in quotes.

The links on the website you provided contain multiple Http GET parameters which are separated with `&` characters. Those will be interpreted by the shell if you don't escape them. The easiest way to do so is enclosing the whole url in quotes:

```
wget "http://www.example.com/download.php?param1=hello&param2=world"
```

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work unfortunately